# Ajax Jquery POST method not working in ASP.NET after changing Jquery version to jquery-3.6.3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, post

I'm changing Jquery version from jquery-1.10.2 to jquery-3.6.3 but the method callings are not working due to this version change. My .NET Framework version is 4.7.2
I have used the new reference like below:

```
<script src="../Scripts/Version3.6.3/jquery-3.6.3.min.js?version=<%=ApplicationVersion.GetApplicationVersion()%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

calling client side JQuery POST method:

```
$.post("/employer/employerbrowse.aspx/SelectEmployer",
                    { key: key },
                    function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        alert(data);
                    });
```

c# method:

```
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
        public string SelectEmployer(string key)
        {
            string strUrl = "";
            
          
            return strUrl;
        }
```

After calling the "SelectEmployer" method it redirecting to page load only not in the desired page method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use AJAX to make the call to webMethod

```
 $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "employerbrowse.asmx/SelectEmployer",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ key: _key}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }
            );
```

Further ... I notice your webmethod is in a normal aspx page, whenever ive tried that it hasnt worked and needed to add a Web Service (asmx) but you might be alright... Youd keep js/ajax call in aspx page if using this.